# Javascript CryptoJS HmacSHA256 in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

Is it possible to write these functions in Python?

```
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var v = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `hmac` and `hashlib` from the standard library.

```
import hashlib
import hmac

message = b"Message"
key = b"Secret Passphrase"

h = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha256)
print(h.hexdigest())
```

Gives output `32c647602ab4c4c7543e9c50ae25e567c3354e1532b11649ce308e6e2568d205`, which is identical to `v` in answer.